# Ground under PCB pads for wire dipole?

Tags: pcb, antenna, ground, pad, dipole

I have a wire dipole antenna that I am connecting to a PCB.  I know that ground should be cleared under most antennas.  However, in my case the wire will be mounted away from the PCB.  Do I need to clear the ground away from and underneath the pads that the two wires of the dipole will solder to?

Comment: What frequency are you looking at? In the case of a dipole, you really want to just keep everything away from it as much as possible. Putting the antenna orthogonal to the PCB (thus sticking out up and under the PCB) tends to be beneficial as well.

Comment: Sorry, I was going to post that and forgot.  403MHz.  I'm not worried about the orientation of the antenna.  That is already set and not something I can change.  I'm just concerned with whether or not I can add the grounds under my antenna pads and get some routing space back.